# Atalho para Identar Query Sql

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query

Boa tarde pessoal!

Existe algum atalho no teclado que faça a identação da Query SQL e deixar o código organizado?

No aplicativo Database.Net o comando é o Ctrl + M

Se alguem souber por favor me avise, hoje trabalho com SSMS e uso o DB.Net só pra identar o código

Obrigado

Comment: Tem uma ferramenta que faz isso pra vc, não sei se já ouviu falar do Instant SQL Formatter.

Comment: Recomendo o plugin do Sublime Text [SQLTools](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SQLTools). Ele permite formatar o SQL com o atalho Ctrl+E Ctrl+B

Comment: Geralmente uso o site http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm para realizar a identação automática das querys. Nele é possível selecionar diversos tipos de SGBDs.

Comment: Uma outra alternativa é o Poor Man's, utilizo ele a muito tempo e tem me ajudado. [Site do Projeto](http://architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx) [Link para Dowload da Versão para SSMS](http://architectshack.com/GetFile.aspx?Page=PoorMansTSqlFormatter&File=PoorMansTSqlFormatterSSMSPackage.Setup.1.6.16.msi) Resposta baseada em: [Is it possible to auto-indent a query in Sql Server Management Studio Express? ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090353/is-it-possible-to-auto-indent-a-query-in-sql-server-management-studio-express)